# SwiftUI connecting @Binding to @Published directly in ChildView

Tags: swiftui

We needed to bind to the `@Published` in a ParentView's `@StateObject` being used as a ViewModel. I told my coworker we needed to pass in the entire ViewModel to an `@ObservedObject` in the ChildView, since everything I've read about SwiftUI describes the parent-child data relationships like this:

| Parent View | Child View |
| --- | --- |
| @State | @Binding |
| @StateObject | @ObservedObject |
| @Published (within the @StateObject) | *DOESN'T EXIST* |

He insisted we could just pass in the `@Published` alone to the `ChildView`'s `@Binding` and it would work. Lo and behold, he was right. In the example code below is the documented way to use `@Binding`, along with passing the entire `@StateObject` down into an `@ObservedObject` and binding to the `@Published` directly (which I thought was the only way you could/should bind to an `@Published`), and passing the `@Published` directly into the `@Binding`, which surprisingly does work. You can see in the sample pic that when you type in any of the 3 `TextField`'s, the updates appear immediately in the parent view, proving that the `@Binding` works with all 3 approaches.

Is this a fluke about binding to the `@Published` directly? Or an undocumented-but-valid approach? Why isn't this taught as a standard approach?

```
import SwiftUI

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var publishedStr1 = "I am publishedStr1"
    @Published var publishedStr2 = "I am publishedStr2"
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var stateStr = "I am stateStr"
    @StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildView(stateStr: $stateStr, 
                      myViewModel: myViewModel, 
                      // Why don't I ever see examples using this technique
                      // of passing the @Published directly to an @Binding?
                      // It clearly works.
                      publishedStr2: $myViewModel.publishedStr2)
            Text(stateStr)
            Text(myViewModel.publishedStr1)
            Text(myViewModel.publishedStr2)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var stateStr: String
    @ObservedObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    @Binding var publishedStr2: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Binding to State", text: $stateStr)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            TextField("Binding to ObservedObject",
                      text: $myViewModel.publishedStr1)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            TextField("Binding to ObservedObject's Published",
                      text: $publishedStr2)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

[image: TextFields updating @Binding in Simulator]

Comment: Nah, `@Published` → `@Binding` is pretty common — see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260001/14351818. Although I usually prefer passing down the entire model — I've found it's a bit less glitchy especially when you have a bunch of views

Comment: Thanks for the response on this. Curious why it hasn't been presented more in the various tutorials I saw when learning SwiftU (or even in Apple docs). It makes sense to pass down the enter viewmodel like you said, though, especially since later on there's a good chance you'll need to modify some other property in the viewmodel, which is easier if you already have it there.

Answer (score 0):

`@StateObject` is only when we need a reference type for state. In your case you don't so just use `@State`, e.g.

```
struct ParentViewConfig {
    var publishedStr1 = "I am publishedStr1"
    var publishedStr2 = "I am publishedStr2"
    var stateStr = "I am stateStr"

    mutating func someFunc() {

    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var config = ParentViewConfig()
```

Comment: In our case we have unit tests instantiating the ViewModel and overriding methods in it, which is why we need it to be a @StateObject.

Comment: To be more exact, the unit tests are creating subclasses from the ViewModel and overriding methods in it.

Comment: I appreciate the answer though! It's a good reminder that @State can be an entire struct and not just a single string.

Comment: I would suggest re-architecting the tests - it doesn't make sense so slow the app down and increase memory use for the user because of testing.

Comment: What about if a ViewModel has a reference to the FileManager or a web service and you need to mock the data being returned? So you need to override the methods to simulate the data return?

Comment: Have a look at protocols

Comment: Oh yeah good call